# Communicate between ViewModel and Command

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, mvvm

Am creating a small cashier application, I have my **CashViewModel** having **Sales** filtred by **Date**.

now I've added a **history button** to show sales (*in a window*) grouped by date, then when a user selects a date my **Date** property changes, so i've binded that button to a RelayCommand.

```
 public RelayCommand HistoryCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _historyCommand
                ?? (_historyCommand = new RelayCommand(
                                      () =>
                                      {
                                          //?????????
                                      }));
        }
    }
```

**My problem** is inside the callback Action, **i don't want to call a window directly from here** and for testing reasons .

should I use Messaging (if so should I create a message receiver, or is there other options ???)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a WindowService (it call a window directly), and inject it into the view model.

For example:

```
public interface IWindowService
{
    Result ShowWindow(InitArgs initArgs);
}

public sealed class WindowService : IWindowService
{
    public Result ShowWindow(InitArgs initArgs);
    {
        //show window
        //return result
    }
}

public class CashViewModel 
{
    private IWindowService m_WindowService;

    public CashViewModel(IWindowService windowService)
    {
        m_WindowService = windowService;
    }

    public RelayCommand HistoryCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _historyCommand
                ?? (_historyCommand = new RelayCommand(
                                      () =>
                                      {
                                          var result = m_WindowService.ShowWindow(args);
                                      }));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would you be a little more specific (more details !!)

Answer (score 0):

You can give function name there.

```
private ICommand _historyCommand;
public ICommand HistoryCommand
{
    get { return _historyCommand?? (_historyCommand= new RelayCommand(MyFunction)); }
}


private void MyFunction()
{
     // Function do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use [`EventAggregator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) implementation of [Prism framework](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/). It enables you to send and receive events without any knowledge of the sender and / or receivers.

When you receive related event, you may just execute related code to display the view.

Comment: EventAggregator is the same as Messeging in (mvvm light) here i'll need a receiver, with `IWindowService` you can create a window at Dev & Production , and return directly a RESULT When testing. so am going with that